# Gráfico de barras empilhadas - Rótulos e Ordenação - GGPLOT

Tags: r, ggplot2

Estou construindo um gráfico indicando a população dos estados brasileiros, organizado por regiões, conforme o código abaixo:

```
State <- c("Rondônia", "Acre", "Amazonas", "Roraima", "Pará", "Amapá", "Tocantins",
           "Maranhão", "Piauí", "Ceará", "Rio Grande do Norte", "Paraíba", "Pernambuco", "Alagoas", "Sergipe", "Bahia",
           "Minas Gerais", "Espírito Santo", "Rio de Janeiro", "São Paulo",
           "Paraná", "Santa Catarina", "Rio Grande do Sul",
           "Mato Grosso do Sul", "Mato Grosso", "Goiás", "Distrito Federal"   )

Population <- c(1805788, 829619, 4063614, 522636, 8366628, 797722, 1550194,
                7000229, 3219257, 9020460, 3507003, 4025558, 9473266, 3375823, 2288116, 15344447,
                21119536, 4016356, 16718956, 45094866,
                11320892, 7001161, 11322895,
                2713147, 3344544, 6778772, 3039444)

Region <- c(rep("Região Norte", 7),
            rep("Região Nordeste", 9),
            rep("Região Sudeste", 4),
            rep("Região Sul", 3),
            rep("Região Centro-Oeste", 4))

dfPop <- data.frame(State, Population, Region)

ggplot(data=dfPop, 
       aes(x=Region, weights=Population / 1E+6)) +
  geom_bar(aes(fill=State), color="Black") +
  geom_text(aes(x=Region, y=Population / 1E+6, group=State, label=State),
            position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5), size=3.3) +
  guides(fill=FALSE) +
  xlab("Região do Brasil") + ylab("Milhões de habitantes")
```

O gráfico resultante é o seguinte:

[image: População dos Estados Brasileiros]

Tenho dois problemas que gostaria de resolver e não estou conseguindo

**1. Ocultar rótulo de estados com menos de 3 milhões de habitantes**

Para deixar o gráfico mais claro, quero esconder o rótulo dos estados com menos de 3 milhões de habitantes. Para isso encontrei uma dica para filtragem do data.frame direto no elemento geom_text, de forma a remover estes estados, da seguinte forma:

```
ggplot(data=dfPop, 
       aes(x=Region, weights=Population / 1E+6)) +
  geom_bar(aes(fill=State), color="Black") +
  geom_text(data=dfPop[dfPop$Population > 3E+6,],
            aes(x=Region, y=Population / 1E+6, group=State, label=State),
            position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5), size=3.3) +
  guides(fill=FALSE) +
  xlab("Região do Brasil") + ylab("Milhões de habitantes")
```

[image: População dos Estados Brasileiros]

No entanto, como vocês podem ver, todos os demais rótulos foram deslocados. Como eu poderia esconder os rótulos desejados, sem deslocar os demais?

**2. Ordenar o empilhamento com base na população dos estados (mais populosos embaixo)**

Como alternativa para resolver o problema 1, busquei ordenar cada pilha de acordo com a população do estado, para ocultar o nome dos estados no topo da pilha. No entanto, mesmo ordenando o data.frame de entrada, não consegui fazer esta ordenação visual no ggplot. Alguém consegue me ajudar?

Obrigado pelo apoio!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ao trabalhar com o `ggplot2`, eu sou da opinião de que todas as transformações a serem realizadas nos dados devem ser feitas fora do comando do plot em si. É a minha opinião pessoal, pois acho que assim o código fica mais organizado e fácil de entender. Isto posto, segue a minha solução ao teu problema.

Em primeiro lugar, vou transformar a coluna `dfPop$State` em um fator ordenado de acordo com o tamanho da população de cada estado. Isto vai servir para deixar as tuas barras empilhadas da maneira que tu deseja:

```
dfPop$State <- factor(dfPop$State, levels=dfPop$State[order(dfPop$Population)], 
  ordered=TRUE)
```

Perceba o resultado obtido:

```
dfPop$State
 [1] Rondônia            Acre                Amazonas           
 [4] Roraima             Pará                Amapá              
 [7] Tocantins           Maranhão            Piauí              
[10] Ceará               Rio Grande do Norte Paraíba            
[13] Pernambuco          Alagoas             Sergipe            
[16] Bahia               Minas Gerais        Espírito Santo     
[19] Rio de Janeiro      São Paulo           Paraná             
[22] Santa Catarina      Rio Grande do Sul   Mato Grosso do Sul 
[25] Mato Grosso         Goiás               Distrito Federal   
27 Levels: Roraima < Amapá < Acre < Tocantins < Rondônia < ... < São Paulo
```

Agora a coluna `State` não está mais ordenada por ordem alfabética, e sim por tamanho da população do estado. Depois, vou criar uma coluna chama `StateNamePlot`, que não vai ser fator, mas sim caractere. Ela vai servir apenas para colocar os labels no gráfico. Perceba que estou eliminando desta coluna todos os estados tais que a população é menor do que três milhões:

```
dfPop$StateNamePlot <- as.character(dfPop$State)
dfPop$StateNamePlot[which(dfPop$Population < 3e6)] <- NA
```

Agora é só criar o gráfico de acordo com este novo `dfPop`, mudando apenas alguns detalhes do teu gráfico original.

```
ggplot(data=dfPop, aes(x=Region, weights=Population/1E+6)) +
  geom_bar(aes(fill=State), color="Black") +
  geom_text(aes(x=Region, y=Population / 1E+6, group=State, 
    label=StateNamePlot), position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5),
    size=3.3) +
  guides(fill=FALSE) +
  xlab("Região do Brasil") + 
  ylab("Milhões de habitantes")
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]